# TemplateDoesNotExist error while I am using Class-Based Views in django for updating and deleting a record

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Here, I am trying to update and delete the product, but whenever I click on the Update and Delete Link Buttons, it shows me TemplateDoesNotExist at affiliation/affproduct_form.html and for delete, it shows TemplateDoesNotExist at affiliation/affproduct_confirm_delete.html
[image]

I have created the form and done adding and viewing using function-based views.
Below is my models.py :

```
#Product details uploaded
class AffProduct(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foo')
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    specification = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sale_price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    img1 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    img2 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    promote_method = models.TextChoices
    terms_conditions = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    promote_method = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=promote_choices,
        default='PPC'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_title
```

Below is my views for update and delete function. I have not used class-based views for creating and detail. but for updating and deleting i have done using class-based views.

```
# update view for details
class AffProductUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = AffProduct #model
    fields = ['product_title', 'uid', 'specification', 'sale_price', 'discount', 'img1', 'img2', 'promote_method', 'terms_conditions',] # fields 
    template_name = 'affiliation/affproduct_form.html' # template for updating
    #success_url = "/blink_viewproduct.html" # redirect url

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        product = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == product.user:
            return True
        return False

# delete view for details
class AffProductDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = AffProduct  # model
    success_url = '/blink_viewproduct.html'  # redirect url

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        product = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == product.user:
            return True
        return False
```

Both of the templates is created namingly, 1 . affproduct_form.html for updation, and
2. affproduct_confirm_delete.html.
Both the html pages are located in my affiliation app folder and also a copy is there is templates folder.
Also below is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blink_network),  # redirect to root - path
    path('blink_network/', views.blink_network, name='blink_network'),
    path('AddNewProduct/', views.AddNewProduct, name='AddNewProduct'),
    path('blink_viewproduct/', views.showproduct),
    path('blink_viewproduct/', views.blink_viewproduct, name='blink_viewproduct'),
    path('update/', views.update, name='update'),
    path('update/<int:pk>/', Update.as_view(), name='Post_update'),
    path('affiliation/<int:pk>/update', AffProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='affproduct-update'),
    path('affiliation/<int:pk>/delete', AffProductDeleteView.as_view(), name='affproduct-delete'),
    path('link/', views.link, name='link'),
    path('link/<int:uid>/', views.link_view, name='link_view'),
]
```

Below is my template directory where all the templates are stored.

[image]

This is my app directory:

[image]

And this is my templates directory below:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please provide your template directory for the affiliation app?
When using django GCBV's the directory structure should be as below.

Djangos GCBV's are programmed by default to look in the models directory for
`templates/<app_name>/<specified_templatename>`
or

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects

Assuming you have the default app_dirs set to true..

As per **Django**..

> Thus, when (for example) the APP_DIRS option of a DjangoTemplates backend is set to True in TEMPLATES, a template location could be: /path/to/project/books/templates/books/publisher_list.html

```
affiliation
|
|--templates
     |
     |affiliation
         |
         |-affproduct_form.html.html
         |
         |--affproduct_confirm_delete.html
```

Also, success_url is not a template name, it takes a url name.

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class AffProductUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blink_viewproduct') # the url might not be built yet, so while class is being 'defined' @ runtime we call reverse_lazy
    ...
```

and..

```
class AffProductDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blink_viewproduct') # the url might not be built yet, so while class is being 'defined' @ runtime we call reverse_lazy
    ...
```

Comment: i have added the directory @enjoi4life411

Comment: Pleae add a templates directory and repeat the name of the app as I have above. If no error please upvote!

Comment: means i have to create a folder under affiliation app, named templates, and again inside templates folder, should i have to create an another 'affiliation' folder where the templates must be stored

Comment: Yes, and I provided the link to Django docs.